# Losing precision in parsing unix timestamp with fraction of seconds

Tags: python, pandas

When I am trying to read .csv filename with unix timestamp, it looks like the
column I used to conversion is treat as a string. It leads to loosing precision.
After few experiment I get:

```
>>> import pandas as pd   
>>> import datetime as dt                           
>>> from StringIO import StringIO    
>>> 
>>> input1 = StringIO('unix_timestamp\n1388518220.9870002')
>>> input2 = StringIO('another_col,unix_timestamp\n0,1388518220.9870002')
>>> input3 = StringIO('unix_timestamp,another_col\n1388518220.9870002,0')
>>> 
>>> pd.read_csv(input1, usecols=['unix_timestamp'], date_parser=lambda x: dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(x)), parse_dates={'parsed_unix_timestamp':['unix_timestamp']})

       parsed_unix_timestamp
0 2013-12-31 20:30:20.987000    
[1 rows x 1 columns]

>>> pd.read_csv(input2, usecols=['unix_timestamp'], date_parser=lambda x: dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(x)), parse_dates={'parsed_unix_timestamp':['unix_timestamp']})

       parsed_unix_timestamp
0 2013-12-31 20:30:20.990000    
[1 rows x 1 columns]

>>> pd.read_csv(input3, usecols=['unix_timestamp'], date_parser=lambda x: dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(x)), parse_dates={'parsed_unix_timestamp':['unix_timestamp']})

       parsed_unix_timestamp
0 2013-12-31 20:30:20.987000
[1 rows x 1 columns]

>>> pd.__version__
'0.13.1'
```

It looks like the column order make the difference when handling the type of data.

```
>>> str(1388518220.9870002)
>>> '1388518220.99'
```

Is it bug or expected behavior?

Comment: This looks like a display issue to me, when I print the values (`df.values`) I get: `array([['2013-12-31T19:30:20.987000000+0000']], dtype='datetime64[ns]')`

Comment: what is your numpy version? if its 1.6.1, then @EdChum comment is c orrect.

Comment: @Jeff mine is `1.8.0` so to me this is expected and correct

Comment: If you try `pd.read_csv(input1, usecols=['unix_timestamp'], dtype={'unix_timestamp' : object},  parse_dates={'parsed_unix_timestamp':['unix_timestamp']})` and then convert using `to_datetime` as @Jeff suggests then you should retain the precision you desire

Comment: gr8...so not a display issue (which is what 1.6.x has an issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your convetrsion to floats is causing this, instead, better to read it in with

```
dtype={'unix_timestamp' : object}
```

then

```
df['unix_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['unix_timestamp'],unit='s')
```

It *may* also work if you simply read it in as a float (the default). I *think* their is enough precision. Definitely convert after though.

Comment: I just tried your method and I get `1388518220.9870002` for the result of the conversion, I tried with dtype set to np.float64 and it trimmed the result to `1388518220.99` interestingly

Comment: yeh I think ``object`` is the way to go here (note that *normally* these epoch timestamps are int64 as they represent milliseconds; BUT, in this case (or if you want more precision), then you need to do the conversion after

Answer (score -1):

It's expected behavior. Read [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Maybe [decimal module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) can help you:

```
>>> Decimal('1388518220.9870002') + Decimal('100000000000000.0000000001')
Decimal('100001388518220.9870002001')
```

Comment: _how_ should that help? don't answer when you are _only_ speculating.